# trying to check the answer when the button is pushed

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

There are different answers for every button. I was planing to check by matching with the indexnumber but when try typing in the button action it shows unresolved identifer `randomIndex`. Is there other way to check the answer or make this work?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for _ in 1...3 {
        randomQuestion(queModel: questionModel)

    }

}
func randomQuestion(queModel queModel:QuestionModel){
    let questions = queModel.questions
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questions.count)))

    SignImage.image = questions[randomIndex].question
    AnswerBtn_A.setTitle("\(questions[randomIndex].answers[0])", forState: .Normal)
    AnswerBtn_B.setTitle("\(questions[randomIndex].answers[1])", forState: .Normal)
    AnswerBtn_C.setTitle("\(questions[randomIndex].answers[2])", forState: .Normal)
    AnswerBtn_D.setTitle("\(questions[randomIndex].answers[3])", forState: .Normal)

    // CorrectAnswer = "\(questions[randomIndex].correctAnswerIndex)"

}


@IBAction func ActBtn_A(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func ActBtn_B(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func ActBtn_C(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func ActBtn_D(sender: AnyObject) {         
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare your `randomIndex` outside `randomQuestion` function as shown below:

```
var randomIndex = 0

func randomQuestion(queModel queModel:QuestionModel){
    let questions = queModel.questions
    randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questions.count)))

    SignImage.image = questions[randomIndex].question
    AnswerBtn_A.setTitle("\(questions[randomIndex].answers[0])", forState: .Normal)
    AnswerBtn_B.setTitle("\(questions[randomIndex].answers[1])", forState: .Normal)
    AnswerBtn_C.setTitle("\(questions[randomIndex].answers[2])", forState: .Normal)
    AnswerBtn_D.setTitle("\(questions[randomIndex].answers[3])", forState: .Normal)

    // CorrectAnswer = "\(questions[randomIndex].correctAnswerIndex)"

}
```

Now you can read `randomIndex` in any method in your class.